# Putting second column below the first column first item

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to set up the grid in Bootstrap using the following order in mobile and tablet?

```
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
|   | 2 |
```

becomes:

```
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
```

but right now it is:

```
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
```

The second column is much longer than 1 and 3 and if I do two rows, the number 3 item is below the second item because it is in the second row and there are lot of empty space after 1. I'm trying to put the 2 items below the 1st item in mobile and tablet.

If I just list everything it is becoming 1, 3 and 2 in mobile and tablet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

css:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media (min-width: 768px) { .col-sm-6:nth-child(2){float:right;} }
</style>
```

html:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-6">1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">2<br>2<br>2<br></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">3</div>


    </div>  
</div>
```

see: http://bootply.com/103494

Comment: this not work in 2022. or just for me. i dont know.

Answer (score 2):

May this code can help you:

http://jsfiddle.net/d5DH2/3/

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="bordered col-1">Column 1</div>
    <div class="content-right">
        <div class="bordered col-2">Column 2</div>
        <div class="bordered col-2">Column 2</div>
        <div class="bordered col-2">Column 2</div>
    </div>    
    <div class="bordered col-3">Column 3</div>
</div>


body{
    margin: 0 ;
    padding: 0;
}

.bordered{
    min-height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 10px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.col-1{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.col-3{
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
}

.content-right{
    float:right;
    width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px){
   .content-right,
   .col-3,
   .col-1{
       float: none;
       width: auto;
    }
}
```